# wrong icons flutter android material

Tags: flutter, flutter-material

My app displays wrong icons.
In my material\icons.dart shows a totally diferent name for the icon.
[image]

Comment: did you make any edit on source code?

Comment: No. I did flutter upgrade and also android studio upgrade.

Comment: What's current version of them

Comment: I'm using beta branch (2.5.0-5.2.pre). But when i choose stable brach, it's the same. I've also tried "flutter clean", "flutter pub cache repair" without success

Answer (score 0):

Problem with flutter version. Nedded to the correct flutter version/update.